# Ubuntu 17.10 4 displays, no desktop on two

Tags: nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors, display

I have 2 GPU in my workstation and 2 displays per GPU connected via DisplayPort cables.

First two displays connected to GPU-0 works fine, have desktop and all functionality.
Next two displays are on, I can move cursor there but mouse arrow changes to X and apart of that I can't have anything on these screens.

I configured org.conf using Nvidia-settings 
Align 2 displays at top and two at bottom, moving cursor works.
Xinerama is disabled because with enabled X windows doesn't start.

Could anybody have similar configuration working and could share some know-how ?